# Makefile generic rule where target and prerequisite names differ

Tags: makefile, protocol-buffers, automake

I'm currently trying to get a hybrid C/Java build infrastructure making heavy use of protocol buffers set up to work correctly. While Ant is doing the final Java build, there are a lot of JNI prerequisites being done in Autoconf/Make prior to this, and Ant is then being called from my makefile.

Here's a snippet of what I'm trying to get working:

```
PROTODIR = ../server/protos

PROTO_SOURCE = File_1.proto File_2.proto
BUILT_SOURCES = $(PROTO_SOURCE:.proto=.java)

# Tell make where to look for proto files
vpath %.proto $(PROTODIR)

# Build java from proto files
src/appname/proto/%.java: %.proto
    protoc --java_out=src/ --proto_path=`dirname $<` $<
```

The problem? protoc Java removes underscores in the file names, and hence the %.java and %.proto file names don't match. The build does end up working, but it rebuilds the proto files (and hence anything that depends on the proto files) every time Make is called.

How can I make it so that the %.java and %.proto can differ, or is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a way to do it using eval and a defined macro.

```
PROTODIR = ../server/protos
PROTOGENDIR = src/appname/proto/

PROTO_SOURCE = File_1.proto File_2.proto
BUILT_SOURCES = $(subst _,,$(addprefix $(PROTOGENDIR), $(PROTO_SOURCE:.proto=.java)))

# Tell make where to look for proto files
vpath %.proto $(PROTODIR)

# Build java from proto files    
define BUILDPROTO
$(subst _,,$(addprefix $(PROTOGENDIR), $(PROTONAME:.proto=.java))): $(PROTONAME)
        protoc --java_out=src/ --proto_path=`dirname $$<` $$<
endef

$(foreach PROTONAME,$(PROTO_SOURCE),$(eval $(BUILDPROTO)))
```

Inspired by: http://make.mad-scientist.net/the-eval-function/